# Third degree polynomial and search for its roots

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have the question in textbook: "The incidence of breast cancer per $100000$ women may be approximated by $I(x) = -0.000054x^2 + 0.0067x^3 - 0.0997x^2 - 0.84x - 0.25$. Where $x$ is a women's age. Use this function to estimate the ages where $300$ out of $100000$ women have breast cancer"

The only one solution that I can see is finding the roots of an equation from an identity of the form: $300 = -0.000054x^2 + 0.0067x^3 - 0.0997x^2 - 0.84x - 0.25$ But I can not find these roots without a calculator, and two roots will be complex. So this is only one way for solving this problem?

What will happen to the roots if I differentiate a function once or twice?

Comment: You are just asked to estimate the root, so it will suffice to compute a few values of the function.  To be sure, just evaluating this function at a few values will require a calculator,  Differentiation won't help you find the value you seek.  It could help you sketch the graph, but I expect it's easier to just compute a few values.

Comment: @lulu using the cardano formula?

Comment: @Arsenii: Since it is an estimate, why not plot the function and see the root at $x \approx 43$ or using Newton's Method $x = 42.5666$?

Comment: @Moo And about complex roots just forget?

Comment: What would the complex roots even mean in this context since age is not complex?

Comment: No, cardano is overkill.  Just compute the function at a few integer values.  If you want more precision, compute the function at half-integer values.  If you need still more precision, use Newton.

Comment: @Moo You are right, it is meaningless

Comment: @lulu thanks, I understand you, and I will do it

Comment: Add the x$^2$'s together.

Comment: Is it $x^4$ instead of $x^2$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Perhaps a mistake in the textbook. I rewrote literally

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Would it have changed something?

Comment: You will get a different answer if it would be $x^4$, that's all.